# Transaction returns E00027 but response code is 1

Tags: authorize.net

Using the Java API version 1.8.6 to commit a simple credit card payment transaction in live mode against a real gateway account.
TransactionResponse getResponseCode() returns 1 which is supposed to mean that the transaction succeeded.
But getErrors() includes an error E00027 that suggests that the transaction failed.
Did the transaction succeed or not?

Comment: E00027:The transaction was unsuccessful.

Comment: E00027:An approval was not returned for the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

A responseCode of 1 means the gateway successfully received and processed your request.  However, the result was an error [E00027](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html?code=E00027) and the transaction was not successful. You'll want to check the errorCode field for the specific problem.